# React-leaflet center of an array of positions

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

Helllo! I'm trying to set the center of the map based the following array:

```
[[-23.568767,-46.649907],[-23.565972,-46.650859],[-23.563703,-46.653542],[-23.616359,-46.664749],[-23.624203,-46.683369],[-23.565972,-46.650859],[-23.572424,-46.65384],[-23.610235,-46.69591],[-23.609215,-46.69753],[-23.608786,-46.697448],[-23.617262,-46.674802],[-23.620757,-46.673658],[-23.625349,-46.692239],[-23.565972,-46.650859],[-23.564909,-46.654558],[-23.642676,-46.672727],[-23.608786,-46.697448],[-23.610652,-46.686046],[-23.573285,-46.689102],[-23.609215,-46.667182],[-23.609215,-46.667182],[-23.60997,-46.667902],[-23.584718,-46.675473],[-23.584718,-46.675473],[-23.607909,-46.692784],[-23.594718,-46.635473],[-23.564552,-46.654713],[-23.573263,-46.695077],[-23.633372,-46.680053],[-23.64717,-46.727572],[-23.576715,-46.68747],[-23.609215,-46.667182],[-23.609215,-46.667182],[-23.52631,-46.616194],[-23.614064,-46.668883],[-23.608786,-46.697448],[-23.587921,-46.6767],[-23.573691,-46.643678],[-23.573691,-46.643678],[-23.627158,-46.675183],[-23.573263,-46.695077],[-23.573263,-46.695077],[-23.572269,-46.689863],[-23.573263,-46.695077],[-23.628932,-46.665837],[-23.61506,-46.659242],[-23.528071,-46.586955],[-23.595269,-46.669645],[-23.596066,-46.686917],[-23.627158,-46.675183]]
```

I've tried get the bounds with Leaflet.latLngBounds:

```
const bounds = L.latLngBounds(latLngs);
```

and got the following errors:

> leaflet-src.js:1658 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of
>   null
>       at Object.project (leaflet-src.js:1658)
>       at Object.latLngToPoint (leaflet-src.js:1497)
>       at NewClass.project (leaflet-src.js:3931)
>       at NewClass._getNewPixelOrigin (leaflet-src.js:4425)
>       at NewClass._move (leaflet-src.js:4173)
>       at NewClass._resetView (leaflet-src.js:4135)
>       at NewClass.setView (leaflet-src.js:3190)
>       at NewClass.initialize (leaflet-src.js:3132)
>       at new NewClass (leaflet-src.js:300)
>       at Map.createLeafletElement (Map.js:99)
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of undefined
>       at Map.componentWillUnmount (Map.js:258)
>       at callComponentWillUnmountWithTimer (react-dom.development.js:15784)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
>       at safelyCallComponentWillUnmount (react-dom.development.js:15791)
>       at commitUnmount (react-dom.development.js:16159)
>       at commitNestedUnmounts (react-dom.development.js:16190)
>       at unmountHostComponents (react-dom.development.js:16446)
>       at commitDeletion (react-dom.development.js:16498)
>
> The above error occurred in the  component:
>       in Map (created by ShopMap)
>       in ShopMap (created by App)
>       in div (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in StyledComponent (created by styled.div)
>       in div (created by App)
>       in div (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in StyledComponent (created by styled.div)
>       in App (created by AppContainer)
>       in AppContainer (created by Connect(AppContainer))
>       in Connect(AppContainer)
>       in Provider
>
> Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have
>   access to the actual error object in development.
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:210)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
>       at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:17442)
>       at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:18898)
>       at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:18827)
>       at performWork (react-dom.development.js:18735)
>       at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:18709)
>       at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:18578)
>       at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:18387)
>       at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:19055)

Then I tried create a FeatureGroup and add Markers based on the array:

```
const group = new L.FeatureGroup();

positions.forEach((latitude, longitude) => {
  L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(group);
});
```

But results on the following:

```
LatLngBounds {}
```

And the Map component:

```
const ShopMap = ({ shops }) => {
  const positions = shops.reduce((newArray, shop) => {
    return [
      ...newArray,
      {
        latitude: shop.latitude,
        longitude: shop.longitude
      }
    ]
  }, []);

  return (
    <Map center={getLatLngBounds(positions)} zoom={15}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {shops &&
        shops.map(({ latitude, longitude, revenueLowerThanExpected, name }) => {
          return (
            <Marker
              key={name}
              icon={revenueLowerThanExpected ? redMarker : blueMarker}
              position={[
                latitude,
                longitude
              ]}
            />
          );
        })}
    </Map>
  );
};
```

Someone could help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

`Map.center` property expects a `latLng` value but what you are after is [`Map.bounds` property](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html) which:

> A rectangle for the map to contain. It will be centered, and the map
>   will zoom in as close as it can while still showing the full bounds

In case of `Map.bounds` value, it could be provided as an *array of `{lat,lng}`* values, in your case

```
const getLatLngBounds = () => {
  return  [
    [-23.568767, -46.649907],
    [-23.565972, -46.650859],
    [-23.563703, -46.653542],
    [-23.616359, -46.664749],
    [-23.624203, -46.683369],
    ...
  ];
} 




 <Map bounds={getLatLngBounds()} >
    <TileLayer 
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'/>
</Map>
```

Refer [this example](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/components/bounds.js) for a more details.

Or  as `L.latLngBounds` value, here is [a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n78017wmzl) for your reference.